# Append to a list piecewise

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to append piecewise for example

```
list = {{1,2,3},{v,w,x},{a,b,c}}
```

Then append a list which

```
toappend = {{4,5,6,7,8},{y,z},{d}}
```

To get

```
list = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{v,w,x,y,z},{a,b,c,d}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Join[list, toappend, 2]
MapThread[Join, {list, toappend}]
Join @@@ Transpose@{list, toappend} (* thanks: AccidentalFourierTransform *)
Flatten /@ Transpose[{list, toappend}]
MapIndexed[Join[#, toappend[[#2[[1]]]]] &, list]
MapIndexed[Flatten[{#, toappend[[#2[[1]]]]}] &, list]
Flatten[{list[[#]], toappend[[#]]}]& /@ Range[Length @ list]
```

all give

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {v, w, x, y, z}, {a, b, c, d}}